# Problem with the Controller using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

Here is the code that I've used  for the controller:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFormContext, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { TextField, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

function FormInput({ name, label, required }) {
  const { control } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      <Controller
        as={TextField}
        name={name}
        control={control}
        label={label}
        fullWidth
        required={required}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default FormInput;
```

Here is where I call FormInput:

```
import React from 'react'
import { InputLabel, Select, MenuItem, Button, Grid, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import { useForm, FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form'
import FormInput from './CustomTextField'

const AdressForm = () => {
    const methods = useForm()

    return (
        <>
            <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>Shippng Adress</Typography>
            <FormProvider {...methods}>
                <form onSubmit=''>
                    <Grid container spacing={3}>
                        <FormInput required name="firstName" label="First name" />
                      
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </FormProvider>
        </>
    )
}

export default AdressForm
```

And I get this error:

> "TypeError: props.render is not a function"

[image]

I'm trying to use the react-hook-form to make the form in the adressForm but I have a problem with the controller.

Comment: Which version of react-hook-form are you using ?

Comment: the version is 7.22.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc, the `as` props have been removed in react-hook-form's v7  in favor of `render` props.

Documentation: https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller

Answer (score 1):

To build off @Joris' answer, the `as` prop has been removed in favor of `render` in react-hook-form v7; see the RFC at https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/3714.

The above link provides the following process for updating `Controller`s that have the `as` prop:

```
// old
<Controller as={<input />} />
// new
<Controller render={({ field }) => <input {...field} />} />
```

NB: the usage of the `render` prop also changed in v7:

```
// old
<Controller render={(props) => <input {...props} />} />
// new
<Controller render={({ field, fieldState, formState }) => <input {...field} />} />
```